# Play framework overriding default-dispatcher

Tags: java, playframework

I would ask what I'm doing wrong that function2() works as espected, but function1() not. I'm expecting that overriding default-dispatcher will affect on promises without specified executing context, but function1() is runnig about 8 threads on my PC independent of application.conf. Below configuration is just for tests.

my application.conf:

```
play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-min = 1
          parallelism-factor = 1
          parallelism-max = 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

code:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> function1() {
    Logger.underlying().debug("Executing: {}", "start");
    F.Promise<Result> promise1 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise1");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise2 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise2");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise3 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise3");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise4 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise4");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise5 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise5");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise6 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise6");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise7 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise7");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise8 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise8");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise9 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise9");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise10 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise10");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise11 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise11");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}).map(Results::ok);

    Logger.underlying().debug("Executing: {}", "stop");

    return promise11;
}

public static F.Promise<Result> function2() {
    Logger.underlying().debug("Executing: {}", "start");
    ExecutionContext executionContext = Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("play.akka.actor.default-dispatcher");
    F.Promise<Result> promise1 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise1");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise2 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise2");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise3 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise3");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise4 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise4");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise5 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise5");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise6 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise6");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise7 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise7");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise8 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise8");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise9 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise9");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise10 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise10");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);
    F.Promise<Result> promise11 = F.Promise.promise(() -> {System.out.println("promise11");Thread.sleep(6000); return "";}, executionContext).map(Results::ok);

    Logger.underlying().debug("Executing: {}", "stop");

    return promise11;
}
```

Comment: Is the object you get from `Akka.system().dispatchers().lookup("play.akka.actor.default-dispatcher")` the same as the default dispatcher you get from `Akka.system().dispatcher()`? How does that compare to the value you get from `play.core.Invoker.executionContext()`? The latter is the default ExecutionContext used by F.Promise.

Comment: If I execute `ExecutionContext executionContext2 = Akka.system().dispatcher().prepare();` executionContext2 have a field id with value `akka.actor.default-dispatcher` (without play prefix). If I add this entry In application.conf and use executionContext2 instead executionContext, everything still works fine, but without specified any executionContext behavior is like in question (about 8 threads starts). `ExecutionContext executionContext3 = play.core.Invoker.executionContext().prepare()` and it's id field is equal to executionContext2